# Summing elements from arrays with matching elements

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array that looks like this:

```
original = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2], [5, 4, 2]]
```

I'd like to get a new array whose elements that match the second and third position would sum up its first position to get this:

```
expected_output = [[4, 2, 3], [5, 2, 2], [5, 4, 2]]
```

I got to grouping the elements from the array as follows:

```
new_array = original.group_by {|n| n[1] && n[2] }
# => {3=>[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3]], 2=>[[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2], [5, 4, 2]]}
```

It is still far from my desired output.

Comment: I think you can use a dictionary.

Comment: @alanfcm I updated my original post with what I have tried. Thanks for your interest

Comment: Thanks @zeet, you are a genius and I really appreciate(?) your contribution...

Comment: I think what you have tried is not that far away from what you want, all you have to do is to add the first element of each sub-array, right?

Comment: Thank you guys for your suggestions and free English classes. I appreciate it.

Comment: A _dictionary_ is a synonym for a _hash_. That's all zeet was suggesting.

Comment: I didn't know about the synonym. In that case, I apologize to @zeet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to return a new array of arrays where the first element of each array is the sum of the original array's first element where its second and third elements match:

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2], [5, 4, 2]]

array_groups = arr.group_by { |sub_arr| sub_arr[1, 2] }

result = array_groups.map do |k, v|
  k.unshift(v.map(&:first).inject(:+))
end

result
# => [[4, 2, 3], [5, 2, 2], [5, 4, 2]]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, @Zoran!! This works perfectly for what I need so far!! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

This will produce a similar result using an array grouping rather than combining the two latter numbers.

```
original = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2], [5, 4, 2]]
new = original.group_by {|n| [n[1], n[2]] }
added = new.map{|x| [new[x.first].map(&:first).inject(0, :+),x.first].flatten}
puts added.to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
original.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(f,*rest),h| h[rest] += f }.
         map { |(s,t),f| [f,s,t] }
  # => [[4, 2, 3], [5, 2, 2], [5, 4, 2]]
```

Note that

```
original.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(f,*rest),h| h[rest] += f }
  #=> {[2, 3]=>4, [2, 2]=>5, [4, 2]=>5}
```

`Hash.new(0)` is sometimes called a *counting hash*. To understand how that works, see [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new), especially the explanation of the effect of providing a default value as an argument of new. In brief, if a hash is defined `h = Hash.new(0)`, then if `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` returns the default value, here `0` (and the hash is not changed).

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into the Hash::new